# How to return multiple values under mono?

Tags: .net, json, wcf, rest, mono

I'm building a RESTful WCF host, but I have no idea how to make it return values under mono.
Codes below works fine under .NET but fails under mono(v3.3.0)

Any way out? Thank you!

**Interface**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate="Test", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string Test(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, out int o1, out int o2, out int o3, out int o4);
```

**Host**

[image]

**Fiddler POST(.net)**

[image]

**Fiddler POST(mono)**

[image]

**Exception(mono linux)**

[image]

Comment: seems you found a bug, I recommend filing it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/